# Link a href to other page selected dropdown option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas, jquery-isotope

Here is a question, which google dont seem to have answers.
I have 2 pages : page-1 & page-2.

page-2 have a  element & toggle-button-box with following code:

```
 <ul>
<li><button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">All</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-filter=".a1">a1</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-filter=".b1">b1</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-filter=".c1">c1</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-filter=".d1">d1</button></li>
</ul>
```

SELECT CODE:

```
<select class="form-control filters-select" style="border-radius:0">
<option value="*">All</option> 
<option value=".a2">a2</option>
<option value=".b2">b2</option>
<option value=".c2">c2</option>
</select>
```

Both of the above 2 elements in page-2, using jQuery isotope to filter data.
Now, if i have to use a href in page-1, to link to page-2, so that on click it opens page-2, with selected option or checked button.

How to do it ?

What will be the code inside:

```
<a href"">
```

Thanks Tons

Comment: I dont see the 'A' tags and your page-1  code

Comment: page-1 code contains only: <a href=""> link & page-2 has e elements - box n select

Comment: in general you pass things like this via `$_GET['myVariable']` where the `href` on the fist page would be `page2.php?myVariable=X`

Comment: This $_GET['myVariable'] gonna be used in page-2. Right ? n how n where in code, for buttons n select ?

Comment: actually isotope has an example using hashs you need to read the plugin documentation (bottom of this page http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html),  here is the example http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vErxXj

Comment: But using hash is doing filtering via buttons on same page. How can i use ahref on other page, to make button class on landing page as - is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that using just a href link. You can however put a link like:

**Using javascript**

```
<a href="page2.php#selectAll">
```

and catch the query with javascript in the onload function:

```
var whatToDo = window.location.hash.substr(1);
//depending of whatToDo is, select something.
```

---

**Using PHP**

```
<a href="page2.php?select=All">
```

and catch the `GET` variable in your php to select something.

```
<select class="form-control filters-select" style="border-radius:0">
<option value="*" <?php if ($_GET['select']=="All") echo "selected" ?>>All</option> 
<option value=".a2">a2</option>
<option value=".b2">b2</option>
<option value=".c2">c2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: #selectAll is the id containing buttons/select. Right ? N this code : var whatToDo = window.location.hash.substr(1); must be added in page-1 or page-2. Plz help, m very new to jQuery

Comment: selectAll is just a string I made up, this value comes in the `whattodo` variable where you can check `if  whattodo=="selectAll"` and then using javascript select the correct button. It all comes in page-2

Comment: How to use this for button ? This above code is for option .

Answer (score 0):

This is a untested but should get you started. Using URL parameters you can send data to page 2 from page 1 this can also be done in PHP.

Page 1:

```
<a href="page2.html?button=a1&select=a1">Page 2</a>
```

Page 2:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );

    $('[data-filter="'+ vars['button'] +'"]').addClass('is-checked');
    $('select > [value="'+ vars['select'] +'"]').attr('selected');
});
```

Comment: Its not working. I guess, here u have combined button & select, but , button n select are filtering data independent of each other. Do i need to put it like this : <a href="page2.php>button=.a1"></a> ????

Comment: Thank you all. I solved it Finally. It was done by using - jQuery isotope hash history / URL hash. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I solved it Finally. It was done by using - jQuery isotope hash history / URL hash.